# HP Recovery Disc Does Not Install Properly

Tags: windows-vista

I have some problem trying to restore my PC (HP Pavilion Desktop PC) using the Recovery Manager.

I tried to recover my PC using the discs that were created by the Recovery Manager, but it does not push through.  When during the installation of Windows, it is giving me some `IRQL_MORE_OR_LESS` error, and from there halts.

Using the Recovery Manager of the PC itself does the same thing. It goes into a BSOD and the same messages are supplied.

I am basically stuck and left with no other things to do.

I know that the partition drive for the Recovery is still in the PC but I suspect it may have already been corrupted as well.

What do you advise for me to do?

Comment: Some HP models need the wireless enabled during the recovery process. Post your full model number and OS for further assistance...see this link.....http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/findModel?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us

Answer (score 0):

You could boot into a live cd of some other ntfs supporting os and check to see if the partition is corrupted or not. If not then just use it. If so, then download an iso of the exact same version of windows you have. During registration just enter the key found on your computer physically somewhere.

Comment: I tried to use an old XP cd I got and when I used it, it installed properly. Checked the HDD and no errors whatsoever. When used HP recovery discs which have been orderd, it does install the Vista OS but the recovery does not complete. It hangs into this HP application which does not do anything.